# Can I redo follower events?

Tags: diablo-iii

In act 5 I had a chat with the Templar, after some talking about his order, he took me for a little "chat" with the Grand Maester of the order.

Is there any way for me to redo that "chat" with my current character? Or am I out of luck? And are these small events one time only per character?

Comment: If you reset quests, you'd almost certainly be able to redo it, at a guess.  You can also probably do it if you just start act 5 over again.

Comment: Does reset quests also reset your finished dialogue with followers? Since that's basically what needs to be turned back I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you reset your quests, this will allow you to redo the follower quests as well (given you have reached that part of the campaign).

Comment: Having to redo the whole campaign just for a single battle in act V is rather annoying though :(

Comment: @Arperum I couldn't agree more, but that's the way it is =(

Answer (score 0):

If you re-chat up the follower(s) in question you should be fine. I just canceled both the Templar and Scoundrel quests and was able to get them to show back up by selecting the The Templar's Quest and Restlessness dialog options respectively. I am on The Harbinger quest in ACT V.